# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Video with 'id'=undefined):

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying create a form in which a user can edit an existing video title and description. When sending PATCH request I get the error below. I changed handleSubmit to take the body, as someone suggested and I get 404 now with id undefined with video being read as id. Any thoughts on how to remedy this?

[image]

edit form

```
class Edit extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            video_id: this.props.match.params.id,
            video_title: "",
            video_description: "",
        }
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    update(field) {
        return (e) => {
            this.setState({
                [field]: e.currentTarget.value
            })
        }
    }   

    handleSubmit() {
        // debugger
        //this.props.updateVideo(this.state.video_id)
        const { video_id, ...rest } = this.state
        this.props.updateVideo(video_id, { video: { ...rest } })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="edit-container">
                <form className="edit-form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <label>
                        <input 
                            type="text"
                            value={this.state.video_title}
                            placeholder="Your video's title"
                            onChange={this.update("video_title")}
                        />
                        <div>{this.state.video_title}</div>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input 
                            type="textarea"
                            value={this.state.video_description}
                            placeholder="Your video's description"
                            onChange={this.update("video_description")}
                        />  
                    </label>
                    <button>Edit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Edit;
```

edit container

```
import { connect } from  'react-redux';
import Edit from './edit';
import { fetchVideo, updateVideo } from '../../actions/video_actions';

const mSTP = ( state, ownProps ) => {
    
    return {
        // video: state.entities.videos[state.session.id],
        video: state.entities.videos[ownProps.match.params.id],
        // errors: state.errors
    }
};

const mDTP = dispatch => ({
    fetchVideo: videoId => dispatch(fetchVideo(videoId)),
    updateVideo: video => dispatch(updateVideo(video)),
});

export default connect(mSTP, mDTP)(Edit);
```

video controller

```
    def update
        @video = Video.find(params[:id])
        if @video.update(video_params)
            render :show
        else
            render json: @video.errors.full_messages, status: 422
        end
    end

  
    def video_params 
        params.require(:video).permit(:video_title, :video_description, :owner_id, :video_url)
    end
```

```
export const updateVideo = video => {
    return $.ajax({
        method: 'patch',
        url: `api/videos/${video.id}`,
        data: { video }
    })
}
```

```
export const updateVideo = video => dispatch => {
    return VideoAPIUtil.updateVideo(video)
        .then(video => dispatch(receiveVideo(video)));
}
```

Comment: ```export const updateVideo = video => {
    return $.ajax({
        method: 'patch',
        url: `api/videos/${video.id}`,
        data: { video }
    })
}

Comment: If you ``console.log()`` the value of ``video.id`` immediately before the ``ajax`` call, it has a value?

Comment: console returns undefined

Answer (score 0):

It might be necessary to see the action creators where the HTTP request is actually being made to see how far the arguments to `updateVideo` travel.

At a glance, could you confirm that the argument signature is correct in `updateVideo`?

It is being called like so in the container:

```js
this.props.updateVideo(video_id, { video: { ...rest } })
```

but the mapDispatchToProps function looks like this:

```js
  updateVideo: video => dispatch(updateVideo(video)),
```

Should `updateVideo` only receive one single argument? It looks like you're sending two arguments (`video_id`, `{ video: { ...rest } }`).

Comment: added  code for update action and Ajax request. if i do this.props.updateVideo(this.props.video) i get 500 and ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature

Comment: The HTTP request you're making is important context and it would be difficult to explain any issues without seeing that code or the server logs of what is being sent to the server.

Comment: Did you update this line? `this.props.updateVideo(video_id, { video: { ...rest } })` to something like `this.props.updateVideo({ video: { id: video_id, ...rest } })`?

Comment: Based on this separate SO question it sounds like you got past this issue and you have a different one now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62779177/activesupportmessageverifierinvalidsignature Is that correct?

Comment: this line creates a nested object: {"video"=>{"video"=>{"id"=>"55", "video_title"=>"", "video_description"=>""}}, "id"=>"undefined"}

Comment: jbelick. I get a different error. In the first case the form sends the PATCH request and it rolls back. In the second the PATCH is not being processed because id is undefined

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work, as long as there is user's input for both title and description fields.

```
handleSubmit() {

        const { video_id, ...rest } = this.state
        this.props.updateVideo({ id: video_id, ...rest })

    }
```